# How can I make Flash work with my webcam? 

Tags: 12.04, flash, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash Webcam non responsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117302/flash-webcam-non-responsive)

I've installed and re-installed flash many times on my laptop (Philco 14d-p744lm)

When I use a website that uses the webcam in Flash, for example, Chatroulette or Omegle, and i click on "allow" to allow my webcam to turn on, it doesn't do anything.

This does not happen in Windows 7. What do I need to install/use to make my laptop webcam work with Flash? The problem is not with my webcam because I can use webcam perfectly fine on Skype!

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin/+bug/865672

Here's a workaround: http://www.ironzebra.com/news/42/how-to-get-flash-webcam-to-work-on-ubuntu-linux

Both taken from this answer: [Flash Webcam non responsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117302/flash-webcam-non-responsive)

Comment: This *still* doesn't fix the problem for me.